# IIF statement refuses to return Null

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT TInvoiceDetails.ProductID, IIF([ProductID]="APP-001",Null,[TInvoiceDetails].[#of]) AS [#of]
```

i have got the above sql code, and what i want is this output:

```
ProductID      | #of
____________________
APP-001        | 
something else | 12
```

what i get is this output:

```
ProductID      | #of
______________________
APP-001        | 2500
something else | 12
```

The base table is:

```
ProductID      | #of
______________________
APP-001        | 2500
something else | 12
```

Comment: Not sure about access, but you should probably use `'APP-001'`

Comment: @HoneyBadger, that doesn't actually help.

Comment: Maybe spaces or non-printable characters?

Comment: Can you check for hidden characters in the product ID (`len(ProductID)`) should be 7 for APP-001)

Comment: Try `IIf(Trim([ProductID])="APP-001",Null,[TInvoiceDetails].[#of])`

Comment: @SergeyS. It gave this error mesage: `Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression'Iif(Trim([ProductID])="APP-001",Null,[TInvoiceDetails].[#of]'.`

Comment: Why did you cut @SergeyS.' closing parenthesis?

Comment: @Gustav It still returns same `Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression'Iif(Trim([ProductID])="APP-001",Null,[TInvoiceDet‌​‌​ails].[#of])'.`

Comment: or you could check instr([ProductID],"APP-001") > 0 ?

Comment: @krishKM how do i use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since i used an input mask for `[ProductID]` `>LL?\-000`, then the solution was:

```
SELECT TInvoiceDetails.ProductID, IIF([TInvoiceDetails].[ProductID]="APP001",Null,[TInvoiceDetails].[#of]) AS [#of]
```